# New apartment: this weird matte bathroom flooring stains constantly. What do I do? Should I cover it up or wipe it down with something specific?

Tags: bathroom, flooring, floor, cleaning, maintenance

enter image description here

Dark matte bathroom flooring (not sure if it is tile or what).

Comment: To attach the photo, Edit your question, then click the "mountains" icon at the upper right edge of the edit box

Comment: .... and then leave the code alone that it inserts. What you've posted suggests that you tried it and then got rid of everything but "enter image description here" = the code is how the picture gets inserted. leave it be...

Answer (score 1):

Probably seal or wax it. Might be easier if you figure out what it is first. Perhaps ask the landlord and inquire about what it is and how to maintain it.